# Rich text editor with variables for email letters, localized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I've got an acceptance email letter that we send. It has some user generated data. No problem with a standard erb email template, right? But changing it require redeploy. We also need it in many languages. I'd like an admin interface where we have guys maintaining these texts. Maybe using {{variable}} in some rich text editor, to be replace in Ruby when sending the email? Or use a lightweight CMS?

Summarize:

- rich text
- variables from data to populate them
- localization

The variables(from db) doesn't need localization, just the surronding content.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try tolk (https://github.com/dhh/tolk) it has not been updated for a while but I have used it to translate a site into many languages with variables. There are rake tasks to dump to db and/or yaml locale files plus loads of extras and its written by DHH himself.